# Certain user profiles return 404 errors, others work fine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, user-profile-property

I am interning at a company and they have set me up working on improving the company intranet site, which is a sharepoint 2010 enterprise site. I am trying to make a useful company directory, however when you click on a name in the web part more often than not it will give you a 404 error. This only happens on some accounts however, and to my understanding the last IT team, now working elsewhere, were the ones who set up the initial site and it seems as if those are the only accounts linking properly. But even some of their accounts are giving the 404 error. The user info pages can be found for everyone by going to "My Settings" under the logged in user name in the top right, or by changing the user id in the URL.

Ive searched everywhere and cant seem to figure out why, my only guess would be that its based on whether the profile was imported from AD or actually created in SharePoint, but i have no real basis for that guess. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly my first guess. Run a full profile sync in your User Profile Service Application. If that doesn't work, make sure you have the correct containers in your profile connection using an account that has [Replicate Directory Changes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982%28v=office.15%29.aspx#RDCdomain).

Comment: The auto sync says its running itself every saturday, would this be a full profile sync or just an incremental? And would running a full sync potentially lock users out while its running? I dont want to stop anyone being able to access sharepoint during the work week

Comment: Incremental. You only run a Full Profile sync if you kick it off manually. This won't stop users from accessing SharePoint.